# Windows account for SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, account

- What is the Windows account used to perform SQL Server backups?
- Is it the one under SQL Service is running (as `nt service\mssqlserver`)?
- But what about if the backup is executed by means of a maintenance plan and/or job?
- In this case, the windows account is the SQL Server account service or the Agent service account?

Comment: Backups aren't performed by themselves. The account used is the account of the user or service that executes the `BACKUP` command. In an agent job, it's either the agent account or the proxy account specified for that step. In SSMS or another client application, it's the account used to connect to the database

Comment: It's the service account, not the Windows Login (if any) of the session.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Windows account used to perform SQL Server backups?

The SQL Server Service Account performs the backups.

When running under the default virtual account `nt service\mssqlserver`, the service account can only be granted privileges on the local server.  Processes running under a per-service virtual account access domain resources using the computer account, just like the old NetworkService local account.

So grant the share access to `YourDomain\ServerName$`.